# Static files not found when creating a Blazor/Maui Server App on VS2022 and targeting MacOS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

Creating the Blazor Server template on VS2022 (on Windows) works fine on Windows. If I publish to a folder and target Windows, I can open the app on another windows machine and all is well.
If I publish to a folder and target OSX, I can open the app on a Mac, and the HTML loads, but it cannot find the CSS and favicon unless I copy the files from the "publish" folder to my home folder on the Mac.
Same issue if I use VS2022 for MacOS. Works properly when run from the IDE, if I publish it or run the app from outside the IDE, no CSS gets loaded.

Been searching for weeks for an answer to this, but I think hardly anyone is using VS2022 to create Blazor apps targeting MacOS, Lol!

Does anyone run into this? I've tried playing with app.UsePathBase() and <base href= but no joy so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a genius .NET programmer through my brother. He figured it out in a few minutes. It’s so simple, but had eluded me for ages.

Add 1 line in program.cs:

```
webBuilder.UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
```

Old program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MacOSBlazorApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

After:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MacOSBlazorApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
                });
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this has to be added on MacOS but not Windows. Somehow the defaults are different on MacOS I guess!

Comment: do you know how to do this in the new project template?